# Way to make a job with needs on a generated job

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, devops, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I've been working on a way to implement visual regression testing for my websites.
I'm doing this with Diffy in the gitlab CI:CD now im running into one issue,
I generate jobs to make baseline screenshots to test before and after the push to prod.
The issue with this however is that the testing should happen after this job has been completed, usually I do this with the needs: function with the -job: tag in it.
However since the job is created in an earlier part of the process im having a tough time getting it to work.

This is how I do it currently:

to create the job (done with nodeJS):

```
const getConfig = (project) => `
diff-create-pre-prod-baseline-${project.url_prefix}:
```

and then i have the needs like such:

```
needs:
  - job: diff-create-pre-prod-baseline-${project.url_prefix}
```

anyone know how to get this one to work?